# Symmetric sum of polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, symmetric-polynomials

I have a sequence polynomials $P_n(x_1,...,x_n)$ each with as many variable than its index. It turns out that each one has a symmetric sum identically zero. I would be interested to know if such polynomials (with zero symmetric sum) are known families of polynomials.

For me the symmetric sum is not the standard one but this one, for a function $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ of n variables:

$\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \epsilon(\sigma) \cdot f(x_{\sigma(1)}, x_{\sigma(2)}, \dots, x_{\sigma(n)})$

Where $S_n$ is the permutation group on n symbols and $\epsilon(\sigma) $ is the signature of the permutation $\sigma$

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if these have are well-studied polynomials, but I can at least give a complete characterization of them.

---

A general polynomial in $n$ variables can be written as $$f(x)=\sum_{\alpha} c_\alpha x^\alpha$$
where $\alpha$ ranges over the set of multi-indices $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ such that each $a_i$ is a nonnegative integer, and $c_\alpha$ are constants, only finitely many of which are nonzero. The notation $x^\alpha$ refers to the monomial $x_1^{a_1}x_2^{a_2}\dots x_n^{a_n}$.

Let $\def\S{\mathcal S}\S[f]$ denote the symmetric sum of $f$. First, realize that if $\alpha=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ has any repeated indices, say $a_i=a_j$, then $\S[x^\alpha]=0$. This is because for any permutation $\sigma$, then letting $\sigma(x)$ denote $x_{\sigma_1}x_{\sigma_2}\dots x_{\sigma_n}$, then $\sigma(x^\alpha)$ and $(\sigma\cdot (i\;j))(x^\alpha)$ are the same monomial but with opposite signs in the sum for $\S[x^\alpha]$.

Already, this gives a large class of polynomials whose symmetric sum is zero. However, there are more. Indeed, for each multi-index $\lambda$ whose entries are distinct and strictly decreasing ($\lambda_1>\lambda_2>\dots>\lambda_n$), we can consider the $n!$ monomials whose multi-indices are permutations of $\lambda$:
$$
f_\lambda(x)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n} c_\sigma x^{\sigma(\lambda)}
$$
You can then show that
$$
\S[f_\lambda]=\left(\sum_{\sigma\text{ even}}c_\sigma-\sum_{\sigma\text{ odd}}c_\sigma\right)\left(\sum_\sigma x^{\sigma(\lambda)}\right)
$$
This is zero if and only if the sum of the even coefficients equals the sum of the off ones.

Combining these two observations, we see that a typical polynomial with symmetric sum zero looks something like
$$
\underbrace{x_1x_3-x_1x_2^4x_3^4+7x_2^3+8}_{\text{monomials with repeated powers}}
+
\underbrace{4x_1x_2^4 + 5x_2x_3^4 - 12x_3x_1^2+x_2x_1^4+4x_3x_2^4-2x_1x_3^4}_{\text{groups of permuted monomials w/ distinct powers s.t. sum(even) = sum(odd)}}
$$

Comment: Great Mike thanks a lot. In your last example, the symmetric sum must then be taken on $S_9$ ? also we do not need necessarily to have repeated powers I mean $x_1x_3 + 8$ works also ?

Comment: My last example was over $S_3$; the only variables appearing are $x_1,x_2$ and $x_3$. Also, $8$ does have repeated powers, since $8=8x_1^0x_2^0x_3^0$, so the multi-index is $(0,0,0)$, where the $0$ is repeated. Also, $x_1x_3=x_1^1x_2^0x_3^1$ has the power of $1$ repeated.

Comment: I don't think so because your previous example $(x_1 + x_2)\cdot x_1$ works over $S_3$ but not on $S_2$ as you mentioned.

Comment: Are you saying there is something wrong with my answer? I do not understand what you mean in your last comment. @Gianfranco

Comment: Maybe I didn't understood correctly your answer but what I want say is the following: take polynomial  $(x_1 + x_2)\cdot x_1$ 

1) Over $S_2$:  $(x_1 + x_2)\cdot x_1  - (x_1 + x_2)\cdot x_2 = x_1^2 - x_2^2$ which not zero

2) Over $S_3  : $  First one of the $x_1$ change it as $x_3$ which gives the following symmetric sum

$(x_1 + x_2)\cdot x_3 + (x_3 + x_1)\cdot x_2  + (x_2 + x_3)\cdot x_1 - (x_1 + x_3)\cdot x_2 - (x_3 + x_2)\cdot x_1 - (x_1 + x_2)\cdot x_3$

Comment: Then change $x_3$ into $x_1$ back

= $(x_1 + x_2)\cdot x_1 + (x_1 + x_1)\cdot x_2  + (x_2 + x_1)\cdot x_1 - (x_1 + x_1)\cdot x_2 - (x_1 + x_2)\cdot x_1 - (x_1 + x_2)\cdot x_1$

$ = 0$

Comment: Let $A_n$ be the set of polynomials in the variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$ whose symmetric sum over $S_n$ is zero, and let $P = (x_1+x_2)\cdot x_1$. It seems like you are pointing out that $P\notin A_2$, but $P\in A_3$. I agree with this. It is also true that $P\in S_n$ for all $n\ge 3$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $P\in A_n$ for all $n\ge 3$.